# Bokeh: Updating of legend when using different views

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I have an issue with updating legend_groups in bokeh:

My data is based on four columns: x-values, y-values, categorization, geography. I created a scatterplot in Bokeh with all scatter points coming from the same x- and y-column. I split the scatter points into two categories (0 and 1) based on the categorization column. I then used factor_mark and factor_color to display the two categories with different colors (orange vs blue).

I further used legend_group to create the legend for the scatter plot. That works fine. The legend looks like this:

> 0 orange 1 blue

Here a code snippet:

```
renderer_scatter = plot.scatter(
    x='x', y='y', source=data_provider,
    view=data_provider.geography, size=5, fill_alpha=0.4,
    marker=factor_mark('x', ['hex', 'triangle'], 'categorization'),
    color=factor_cmap('x', 'Category10_3', 'categorization'), legend_group='categorization')
```

I further added a drop-down to my dashboard which specifies the views of my data based on geography.

Unfortunately, the legend_group does not update appropriately when I change the view. Depending on the geography it looks like this:

> 0 blue 1 blue

or

> 0 orange 1 orange

or

> 0 orange 1

and so on.

The scatterplot itself updates perfectly fine.

Do you have any idea what the issue might be?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`legend_group` is a shorthand convenience for computing legend entries *once*, up front, when the figure is created in Python. If you need something that reacts to data changes dynamically, then you want to use [`legend_field`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html?highlight=legend_group#automatic-grouping-browser) which is computed on the "JavaScript side" in the browser. (Or alternatively, you can manage `LegendItem` objects completely manually, adding and removing as the data changes.)

Comment: Hi bigreddot, thanks a lot for your reply. legend_field had the same issues. I fixed it now by adding each legend individually as you recommended. Thanks again!!